# Why helpers throw exception in Meteor

Tags: meteor

Meteor application. I have template helper:

```
Template.channel.helpers({
channels: function() {
    var cursor = News.find({ }, {fields:  { title: 1 } }),
        firstChannel = cursor.fetch()[0];

    console.log(firstChannel);
    Session.set("channelId", firstChannel._id);

    return cursor;
}
```

});

I need save channelId in Session, but Meteor throw exception. This debugger in browser:

```
undefined
debug.js:41 Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined
    at Object.Template.channel.helpers.channels (http://localhost:3000/client/lib/helpers.js?a55983adb497520dfef7f2a4a8692a7e13e1b4f6:11:46)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?77c0809654ee3a10dcd5a4f961fb1437e7957d33:2693:16
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?77c0809654ee3a10dcd5a4f961fb1437e7957d33:1602:16
    at Object.Spacebars.call (http://localhost:3000/packages/spacebars.js?3c496d2950151d744a8574297b46d2763a123bdf:169:18)
    at http://localhost:3000/client/template.channel.js?44d590e72735f4cdd0f546df5204c94f8cc015f9:12:22
    at null.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?77c0809654ee3a10dcd5a4f961fb1437e7957d33:2503:27)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?77c0809654ee3a10dcd5a4f961fb1437e7957d33:1795:16
    at Object.Blaze._withCurrentView (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?77c0809654ee3a10dcd5a4f961fb1437e7957d33:2029:12)
    at viewAutorun (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?77c0809654ee3a10dcd5a4f961fb1437e7957d33:1794:18)
    at Tracker.Computation._compute (http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?192a05cc46b867dadbe8bf90dd961f6f8fd1574f:288:36)
helpers.js?a55983adb497520dfef7f2a4a8692a7e13e1b4f6:10 
Object {title: "Яндекс.Новости: Выставки", _id: "ww2baqF7HhkrDTFA7"}
```

Why console.log(firstChannel) put "undefined" at first and object that I'm expecting after exception? Why it throw exception?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either your news documents don't exist or they have not arrived on the client yet. You need to either [wait on](http://eventedmind.github.io/iron-router/#using-waiton) the news subscription in your route controller, or you need to add a [guard](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/guards). Here's a simple solution:

```js
Template.channel.helpers({
  channels: function() {
    var cursor = News.find({}, {fields: {title: 1}});
    var news = cursor.fetch();

    if (news && news[0]) {
      var firstChannel = news[0];
      console.log(firstChannel);
      // Note that you should do this in your route controller or
      // in an autorun. Helpers should not have side effects.
      Session.set("channelId", firstChannel._id);
    }

    return cursor;
  }
});
```

Because helpers are reactive, your `channels` helper will rerun once the news documents become available.

As noted in the comments, you helpers should never have side effects. Setting your session variable should be done in either the route controller or in an [autorun](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_autorun).

Comment: I'm insert my subscription in Tracker.autorun() and my code is work. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

You want to use _id, and you blocked that field, only title is visible

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I thought that _id return by default in find(). I try change to var cursor = News.find({ }, {fields:  { _id: 1, title: 1 } }), but no changes.

Comment: Ye that might be true, probably my bad, does console.log(cursor) return exception aswell?

Comment: Yes. And I can't understand what a problem. I have publish and subscribe. I see my publish data on client: [{_id:dwedhkfdaf, title: "utreeridg"}, {_id: ewqewqewqe, title: "sajdaskjdsal"}...] I can't understand why _id of first document is undefined.